# LibGDX sprite batch font bad scale rendering

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, scale, spritebatch

I am facing an issue while trying to put a text/dialog system in my game project. When I create a font and call the draw method on it passing the camera updated spriteBatch, each pixel of the font has the same dimension of one sprite.

I get the following render:

[image: font draw scale issue]

What you can see on the picture is the top of the "h" of "hello" with each pixel oversized.
The same camera is used to render the tiles/sprites.

The effect I want to achieve is similar to this:

[image: Elliot quest example]

Here is the code:

```
    // 15 * 12 tile size
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Const.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Const.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/myfont.fnt"));

    // ....

    // p => player position   
    camera.position.x = p.getX();
    camera.position.y = p.getY();
    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "hello", p.getX(), p.getY());
    batch.end();
```

I have tried using `font.setScale()` with no success.

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a **camera** with a bigger viewport (for example pixel perfect of your testing device). And use that to render your font. Also do not create a new font every render, create it at the beginning and use that.

**Edit:**

To calculate the position you should draw the text, it would be like this. Lets suppose your world camera is called "cam", and your text camera is called "guicam". And a GameObject called "object".

```
ratew = guicam.viewportWidth/cam.viewportWidth;  //<--- you should calculate these 2 only once.
rateh = guicam.viewportHeight/cam.viewportHeight;

x = guicam.position.x-(cam.position.x-object.position.x)*ratew;
y = guicam.position.y-(cam.position.y-object.position.y)*rateh;
font.draw(batch, "stuff", x, y);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I want the text coordinate to be the same as the sprite render camera. Do I have to update the coord manually?

Comment: Yep, you have to calculate it manually, I edited my answer to show you how.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `Texture.TextureFilter.Linear` for min & max filters.

Libgdx AssetManager loads bitmap fonts with desired filters:

```
BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter param = new BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter();
param.maxFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
param.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
assetManager.load(fileName, BitmapFont.class, param);
```